# Why is my Amazon slot returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@itsHabib/integrate-an-amazon-lex-chatbot-into-a-react-native-app-1536883ccbed

When I run my chatbot, the JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "dialogState": "Fulfilled",
  "intentName": "MakeUsername",
  "message": "Your username is mikeundefined",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {
    "Name": "mike",
    "Number": "51"
  }
}
```

So, it looks like the number 51 is being stored.

But the output function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event.currentIntent)
    console.log(context)
    let { Name: name } = event.currentIntent.slots 
    let { Num: number } = event.currentIntent.slots 
    callback(null, close({
        contentType: "PlainText",
        content: `Your username is ${name}${number}`
    }))
}
```

prints out

```
Your username is mikeundefined
```

Why is the number undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is undefined because on line 5 you have `let { Num: number }` when it should be `let { Number: number }`.